# Как сохранить enum поле в базу данных room?

Tags: android, kotlin, enum, android-room, room

Необходимо записать в базу данных значение от перечисления `enum`. При создании базы данных возникает ошибка. Что я делаю неправильно?

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "state_of_health")
@TypeConverters(HealthConverter::class)
var health: Health

enum class Health(val value: Int){
    NONE(-1),
    VERY_BAD(0),
    ...
}

class HealthConverter{

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromHealth(value: Health): Int{
        return value.ordinal
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toHealth(value: Int): Health{
        return when(value){
            -1 -> Health.NONE
            0 -> Health.VERY_BAD
            ...
            else -> Health.EXCELLENT
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для создания `Converter` я использовал пример для Java согласно [статье](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/539-urok-11-room-type-converter.html). В ней `@TypeConverter` применялся к сущности или полю. Однако согласно [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#kotlin) нужно добавлять `@TypeConverter` только к `Database`. Пример из документации:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Когда так сделал, ошибка ушла. Возможно с тех пор как была написана указанная статья, изменилась сама библиотека. Или это справедливо только для `Java`.

Comment: Возможно у вас еще где-то был `Health` без аннотации.